# How to a Python custom function to raised value with inner function

Tags: python

This is the current code, tried to print but it return None..can some1 enlightened me how to do it?

```
def calculate(Amount1, Amount2):
    def inner(square,cube):
       square=Amount1**2
       cube=Amount2**3
    return (inner(Amount1,Amount2))

print(calculate(2,4))
```

Expected result (4,64)

Comment: Within calculate you are returning inner, however inner doesn't return anything, therefore you have nothing to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calculate(Amount1, Amount2):
def inner(square,cube):
    square=Amount1**2
    cube=Amount2**3
    return((square, cube))
return (inner(Amount1,Amount2))
```

print(calculate(2,4))

you forgot to return the values from your inner function

Comment: Thank you so much sir, am totally new to this..appreciate it so much